# ArrayFormula for Google Sheets using Sum and IF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

So I have these formulas here

=if(J3="","",sum(J3,M3:N3))

=if(A1="","",index('SHEET1?'!F:F,match(A1,'SHEET1?'!E:E,0)))

I have been trying to find a way to get this as an array but I can't seem to find the solution that works best with this specific format. The problem is that if I do the array formula as is, it shows the sum of the whole range instead of giving the sum per row.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is not supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`, use `+` or `MMULT`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(J3:J="",,J3:J+M3:M+N3:N)))
```

Alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(J3:J="",,J3:J+MMULT(N(M3:N),N(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(M3:N)^0)))))
```

---

`INDEX` is not fully supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`, use `VLOOKUP`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,VLOOKUP(A1:A,E:F,2,FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great! I just edited my post to include another formula I forgot to ask which is how to array this 

=if(A1="","",index('SHEET1?'!F:F,match(A1,'SHEET1?'!E:E,0)))

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)